# Как перемешать массив таким образом, чтобы модуль разности любых соседних чисел был не меньше чем 5?

Tags: c++

Заполнить одномерный массив размером 200 элементов случайными и неповторяющимися числами в диапазоне 1 – 200.

Перемешать данные в массиве таким образом, чтобы модуль разности любых соседних чисел был не меньше чем 5.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime> 
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));  

    int const n = 20;   
    int a[n];   
    int b;  
    int c = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        b = rand() % n;
        if (a[b] != 0) {
            for (int k = b + 1; k <= n; k++) {
                if (k == n) {
                    k = 0;
                }
                if (a[k] == 0) {
                    a[k] = i; break;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            a[b] = i;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << setw(3) << a[i];
    }

// Непосредственно перемешка массива таким образом, чтобы модуль разности любых соседних чисел был не меньше чем 5  
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << setw(3) << a[i];
    }
    system("pause>null");
}
```

Comment: Не испоьзовать для этого слово "сортировать".

Comment: Если ни на что больше не смотреть,  вы инициализируете все элементы массива нулем, а потом проверяете случайно выбранный элемент  равен нулю или нет... И что значит " Непосредственно сортировка массива"?..

Comment: Ранее действие было заполнить одномерный массив размером 200 элементов случайными и неповторяющимися числами в диапазоне 1 – 200, а вот следующее действие уже сортировка, которое я не сумел сделать, всякую чушь писал но ничего не работало, надеюсь на помощь

Comment: Что значит "перемешать массив"? Вам нужно, чтобы финальные перестановки были непредсказуемыми?

Comment: Да именно это мне и нужно, чтобы они были непредсказуемыми

Comment: @СашаДарий Значит вам нужно с равной вероятностью выбирать одну из всех возможных подходящих перестановок?

Comment: Скорее всего да.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы попробовал отсортировать массив, а потом проходить по нему многократно - сначала выбираем первый символ, потом идем дальше, пока не встретим первый же, который на 5 или больше больше первого, и так дальше - пока не дойдем до конца массива. Все выбранные переносятся в новый массив. Как дошли до конца - начинаем заново, сначала.

```
1 1 2 8 10 15 22
```

первый проход:

```
1  8  15  22              1 2 10
```

второй:

```
1  8  15  22  1  10       2
```

третий:

```
1  8  15  22  1  10  2
```

Как-то так. Могут быть массивы, которые неполучится так "отсортировать", как надо - скажем, когда все элементы одинаковы.

Comment: В условии задачи ясно сказано, что содержимое массива заранее известно. Если вы его отсортируете, вы получите `1, 2, ... 200`. В результате ваш алгоритм будет давать одно и то же. И где же тут непредсказуемые перестановки в результате??? Если бы всегда можно было давать "одно и то же" на выходе, то ответ был бы готов сразу: `1, 101, 2, 102, ..., 100, 200` и ничего решать не надо было бы.

Comment: @AnT В условии говорится о "массив размером 200 элементов случайными и неповторяющимися числами в диапазоне 1 – 200." (Глупо конечно) И ничего не говорится о том, что конечный результат должен быть случайным.

Comment: Автор в комментариях сделал уточнения.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы делал так:

1. Заполнить массив последовательными числами от 1 до 200.
2. Пробежать циклом i от 1-го до последнего элемента, для каждого выполняя следующую проерку

   1. Если элемент не удовлетворяет условию, то выбрать случайное j из диапазона массива.
   2. Если i не равно j и перестановка этих элементов местами сделает условие выполненным для обоих, то переставить, иначе увеличивать j на единицу (обнуляя при выходе за массив), пока условие не выполнится.

Таким образом не более чем за 40000 операций массив будет перемешан нужным образом.